# When I click on the "How do I search?" header, the browser shows me the top of the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

In the FAQ page, when I click on the "[How do I search?](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#search)" header, and the section is expanded, I am moved to the top of the page.

[image: screenshot]

That is not what happens with the other headers in the same page, such as "[May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)" for which its status (collapsed, not collapsed) is changed all times I click on the header, moving me to the top of the page.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I am using Safari version 5.1 (7534.48.3), and the SE revision is 2011.8.24.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this was my fault. We have

`id="search"`

there and also in the header. I changed it so it will now be

https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#searching

instead of

https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#search